# Get username by id in Twitter Api

Tags: api, twitter

How can I get the user name by userid via a request to the Twitter Api?

Some other methods, like `followers/ids`, give us as response an array of IDs, from which I am not sure how I can get their usernames.

The response of the method "`followers/ids`" looks something like this:

```
{
"ids": [782235942383972400, 16664925, 839240398010781700, 39606379, 19713521, 
...
...
...
...
...
899462802, 198446818],
"next_cursor": 0,
"next_cursor_str": "0",
"previous_cursor": 0,
"previous_cursor_str": "0"
}
```

How I can get the username from these ids? I want something like what [this webpage](https://tweeterid.com/) does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=ID` and see the `screen_name` property of the returned JSON object.

Reference: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json

Answer (score 3):

This has changed in the Twitter 2 api. To get the username of a single user:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/123456
```

For multiple users (up to 100), use:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users?ids=123456,456789"
```

Click [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting multiple Twitter users from `followers/ids`, you'll probably want to look up the corresponding screen names in bulk. The `users/show` API endpoint mentioned in the other answer only handles one user. For up to 100 users, use [`users/lookup`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup).